# mysql - display all group name and show the name belong to that group

Tags: mysql

- **member** table
  ID  classname  name  groupID
  1         1A           Ali          1
  2         1A           Abu        3
- **group** table
  groupID  groupname
       1          Orange
       2          Blue
       3          Green
- Output that I want
  groupname  name
     Orange       Ali
     Blue
     Green        Abu
- I tried with this query and can't get the above output:

  ```
  select g.groupname, m.name 
  from group g, member m
  where m.groupID = g.groupID && m.classname = '1A';
  ```
- How should I modify it in order to get the above output?

Comment: Try not to use word already used as SQL syntax like "group"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` to get groups that have no members.

```
SELECT g.groupname, IFNULL(m.name, '') name
FROM group AS g
LEFT JOIN member AS m ON g.groupID = m.groupID AND m.classname = '1A'
```

Comment: g.groupID == m.groupID => g.groupID = m.groupID

Answer (score 0):

Here use

```
SELECT g.groupname, COALESCE(m.name,'') -- Will return '' instead of (null)
FROM groupe AS g LEFT JOIN member as m using(groupID)
```

And here a fiddle SQL working

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37bccc/11